# Cannot initialise subclass of command object using properties?

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.4.4. In a controller I have used a command object for handling input from a view. That works fine. But now I want to use subclasses for command objects. Depending on some id in the `params` I want create a specific subclass for the command object. Next I want to fill this command object using this syntax:

```
def finish() {
    final commandObject = createSubclassInstance(params.task.id)
    commandObject.properties = params
    ...
}
```

The latter assignment fails with the error message "Cannot set readonly property: properties for class: ".

I read in the documentation that the `properties` field works for domain classes. Does it not work for subclasses of command objects?

Comment: If all you need is to copy properties from one object to another, then http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerHelper.html#setProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map) `InvokeHelper.setProperties` method could be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind properties from the request to a command or any other object, you can use:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance(command, params)
```

This and the other static methods of the `DataBindingUtils` class are the real underlying methods that Grails uses to bind commands/domains with all the Grails binding features (listeners, binding annotations like `@BindUsing`, ...) and validate it, returning a BindingResult object. If you handle the `properties` property, you are loosing a lot of great binding features from Grails.

PS: Pay attention with these methods you can bind from `params`, a Map, the request (if the request hava a POST with a JSON).